# ProxmosVE - рекомендуемый размер SWAP

Tags: сервер, администрирование, proxmox, swap

Установлен ProxmosVE 5.4-13. 
В мануале Proxmos указан макс. рекомендованный размер SWAP - 8Gb.
Инженер в ДЦ отвел на SWAP 32Gb (наверное, исходя из логики, что размер SWAP=RAM).

Вопрос к админам-практикам (у кого есть реальный опыт эксплуатации ProxmosVE):

**есть ли смысл уменьшать размер SWAP до 8Gb ??**

```
# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 223.6 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x4f3d1dc4

Device     Boot  Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *      2048    499711    497664   243M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       501758 468860927 468359170 223.3G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       501760 468860927 468359168 223.3G 8e Linux LVM

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.


Disk /dev/mapper/mil--145363--vg-root: 191.7 GiB, 205806108672 bytes, 401965056 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/mil--145363--vg-swap_1: 31.7 GiB, 33990639616 bytes, 66387968 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```